# Get processed word file from c# endpoint to nodejs server

Tags: c#, node.js, asp.net-mvc, axios

I have a nodejs server that sends a GET request with [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to a c# endpoint with json as a parameter. My c# api uses Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize the json, then it reads a word file into memory, and inserts data. The final step I need is for this api to respond by sending the modified document back to the nodejs server. Currently, the c# endpoint is called, and a response is sent back. Upon writing the word document using the [archiver library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) and opening it, a dialogue box appears, saying "Word found unreadable content in export0.docx. Do you want to recover the contents of this document? If you trust the source of this document, click Yes"

```js
async exportToDotnet() {
    return await axios.get(`https://localhost:8082/test/${JSON.stringify(this)}`, { responseType: 'arrayBuffer' }).catch(err => {
        console.log(`ERR `, err);
    }).then((axiosResponse) => {
        const data = axiosResponse.data;
        console.log(`DATA `, data);
        console.log(`DATA LENGTH '${data.length}'`);
        return data;
    });
}

async function writeZipFile(resultFromExportToDotnet) {
    const output = createWriteStream('exported.zip');
    output.on("close", () => {
        console.log("success????");
    });
    const archive = archiver('zip');
    archive.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('error in archive ', err);
    });
    archive.append(form, { name: `export0.docx` });
    archive.pipe(output);
    await archive.finalize();
}
```

```cs
[HttpGet("test/{json}")]
    public byte[] ExportDocumentBuffer(string json)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called");
        //Converts the json passed in to a FormInstance Object
        FormInstance form = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FormInstance>(json);
        //Read the dotx into memory so we can use it. Would it be better to just use System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes()?
        MemoryStream dotxBytes = ReadAllBytesToMemoryStream("test.dotx");
        //Read the file bytes into a WordProcessingDocument that we can edit
        WordprocessingDocument template = WordprocessingDocument.Open(dotxBytes, true);
        template.ChangeDocumentType(WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
        template = ParseFormAndInsertValues(form, template);
        byte[] output = dotxBytes.ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine($"BYTES '{output.Length}'");
        return output;
    }
    ///<summary>Reads all Bytes of the provided file into memory</summary>
    ///<param name="path">The path to the file</param>
    ///<returns>A MemoryStream of the file data</returns>
    public static MemoryStream ReadAllBytesToMemoryStream(string path)
    {
        byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        MemoryStream destStream = new MemoryStream(buffer.Length);
        destStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        destStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return destStream;
    }
```

**Things I've tried**

- Changing the axios responsetype to 'stream', converting the response to a buffer with a function, and writing it to a file

```js
function stream2buffer(stream) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const _buf = [];

        stream.on("data", (chunk) => _buf.push(chunk));
        stream.on("end", () => resolve(Buffer.concat(_buf)));
        stream.on("error", (err) => reject(err));

    });
}
```

- Changing my c# method to return a HttpResponseMessage

```cs
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new ByteArrayContent(dotxBytes.ToArray())
            };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "exampleName.docx"
            };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
```

Logging the length of byte[] and logging data.length produce 2 different numbers (52107 and 69476, respectively). Is this just a serialization issue? Obviously I'm missing something. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to have been a few things: I used `template = WordProcessingDocument.Open()`, but never called `template.Save()` or `template.Close()` and as such, my changes were never written, and the file was still open. Once I got my byte array output, I used `Convert.ToBase64String(output)` and returned the string. On the NodeJs side, I changed the responsetype to 'text', and returned `Buffer.from(axiosResponse.data, 'base64');` and wrote the file that way.